# Does a main verb undergo inversion in "Has he any shame?"

Tags: syntax, english, verbs, inversion

My undergraduate textbook builds a case to posit separate classes of verbs as lexical, auxiliary, modal in nature. One criterion is how auxiliary and modals (unlike main verbs) undergo inversion but the sentence "Has he any shame" sounds perfectly grammatical to me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Be, do, have are special.

Comment: Inversion of main verb "have" is becoming unusual in American English.

Comment: I would say that main-verb have-inversion in spoken American English has become ungrammatical in the last 50 years. It's mostly recognized from archaic texts like Bah Bah Black Sheep.

Comment: It's not so much ungrammatical as it is archaic, at least in the US. When Robert Welch asked Sen McCarthy whether he had any shame at long last, he used this construction, which was already highly formalized, to make the punch stronger.

Comment: I've no idea why you or the other commentators here think that "have" is a lexical verb in your example. It isn't - it's an auxiliary, as evidenced by the fact that it uses inversion rather than _do_ support to form interrogatives like yours.

Comment: OK, so a syntax fairy comes along and changes the inverted _have_ into a real auxiliary verb with her magic wand. She's already deleted the subject of _have_ and its _for_ complementizer, so this is no trick at all.

Comment: @jlawler, recall that Joseph (ahem) Welch was born in 1890, well beyond "the last 50 years". I can comprehend currently ungrammatical things written by Shakespeare and Chaucer, which my grammar does not compute. From the POV of individual grammar, it's out, though from the POV of social grammar, "thee" is also in.

Comment: Interesting to know if anyone esp. the OP accepts "Had Tom a heart attack?" or "Has the dog a bone?".

Comment: Not in the United States, at any rate. If you say it in the US, you should have some UK accent to pronounce it in, because it marks you as not a native.

Comment: Welch asked not about shame but about “sense of decency”, in case anyone wants to look it up.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence *Has he any shame?* is not a productive construction in my American English. If, however, the example is changed to *Have you no shame?*, then it works perfectly well for me. But in such a case, the sentence is likely frozen, that is, fully lexicalized. That subject-verb inversion is generally not productive with lexical *have* can be seen by constructing random examples (as suggested by user6726 in the comments):

(1) *Has Frank a car? vs. Does Frank have a car?

(2) *Have they any pets? vs. Do they have any pets?

(3) *Had he an excuse for not helping? vs. Did he have an excuse for not helping?

One can probe for the reasons why certain limited cases of subject-verb inversion with lexical *have* are, although archaic, still encountered in English. My guess is that the construction hearkens back to a earlier stage of English when the V2 principle (verb second) of Germanic was more robustly present. Note in this regard that modern German forms all such questions with subject-verb inversion of the finite verb, regardless of whether the finite verb is an auxiliary or a lexical verb, e.g. *Hast du etwas zu trinken?*, lit. 'Have you something to drink?'.

The reason inversion has survived somewhat with lexical *have*, but not more generally with all standard content verbs, is precisely due to the complete overlap in form of auxiliary *have* and lexical *have*. Such overlap exists only with one other verb, namely with *do*, that is, there is auxiliary *do* and lexical *do*. Hence a related question is why there seems to be an absence of archaic cases of subject-verb inversion with lexical *do*, e.g. * *Does he always the work?*.

Comment: The sentence given is quite unremarkable in British English too. “I haven’t any money” is also quite normal. Using _do_ support is more common, but the ‘direct’ usage is still common enough as well, if a bit on the formal side.

Comment: I agree with @JanusBahsJacquet, and I would say that this is a change in the last fifty years. When I was young, we would use _Do you have_ only in a habitual sense: the normal British form was _Have you got_, more formally _Have you_. _Do you have_ . was definitely an Americanism to me. See [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+you+have+any%2Chave+you+any%2Chave+you+got+any&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20you%20have%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20you%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20you%20got%20any%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet. Your comment is verified by searches I've just done in the BNC. Thanks. However, inversion with an auxiliary (i.e. _have you got_ or _do you have_) is many times more frequent than inversion without one (i.e. _have you_).

Comment: @Colin Fine. Thanks for the link to that ngram search. Very informative!

Comment: @TimOsborne: while _have got_ can function as the perfect of _get_, its most common use is different. _Have_ is substantive, not auxiliary. (I'm not sure how to describe _got_ in this construction. I'm sure it mostly a prosodic feature - an extra syllable that can be stessed). So _Have you got_ is a variant of _Have you_, not something that in any way patterns with _Do you have_.

Comment: For me the got is a PP and have is an auxiliary, and in that sense it does pattern with *do you have*. I had an elderly and very traditional lecturer who would say *have you a pencil*, which sounded absolutely ridiculous to the entire class of (mostly) British English speakers. I don't think that would be the case if the *got* in *have you got a pencil* was merely prosodic.